# 301 Redirect to a PDF

Tags: .htaccess, pdf, redirect

Is there a way to redirect a directory directly to a .pdf file? I have tried putting something like this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 301 /newsletters/today/ http://example.com/file.pdf
```

This does not work. Is there a better way to do this?

I know that redirects from my `.htaccess` file are working as I am able to redirect the same page to another directory by altering the code to something like this:

```
Redirect 301 /newsletters/today/ /newsletters/yesterday/
```

The redirect just does not happen when it is pointed to a `.pdf` file.

Comment: What was the result when you tried it? No redirection at all?

Comment: No, there was no redirection at all.

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located and what URL did you enter in browser?